# SQL Subtract corresponding elements in separate tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, sql-update

So i have 2 tables, both share the key "Product ID", i need to subtract where they match, for example

```
Table 1
Key    Value
1       70
2       50
3       12
4       5
5       18
```

```
Table 2
Key    Value
2       5
3       3
4       1
5       1
```

and i need the output

```
Output
Key    Value
1       70
2       45
3       9
4       4
5       17
```

i tried

```
Update Table1
Set Table1.Count = Table1.Count - (
Select Table2.Count
From Table2
Where Table2.ID = Table2.ID
);
```

But this sets the value of Key 1 to null

I also tried putting a join before the Where, but that gave me the error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL"`

Comment: Just do two updates.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates that you are using Oracle, not MySQL as you tagged.

Problems with your query:

- the correlation clause in the suqbuery is wrong: `Table2.ID = Table2.ID` succeds for all rows in `table2`, and hence returns more than one row, hence the error that you are getting
- you need to handle the case when the subquery returns no rows, otherwise the `null` value propagates to your update: `coalesce()` can be used for this

Consider:

```
update table1 
set count = count - coalesce(
    (select t2.count from table2 t2 where t2.id = table1.id),
    0
);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
update table1 
set count = (select t2.count from table2 t2 where t2.id = table1.id)
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = table1.id)
```

Comment: i did at one point try using coalesce, but wasnt sure how to use it, thanks for the help and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` including `COALESCE` function in order to update non-matching records along with preventing to have null values :

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    SET t1.Count = Coalesce(t1.Count,0) - Coalesce(t2.Count,0)
```

<kbd>[Demo for MySQL Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b55b03d96ef01967473878b839e35a5a)</kbd>

**Update** : seems that question is retagged Oracle. Then you can use such a `MERGE` Statement :

```
MERGE INTO Table1 t1 
USING Table2 t2 
ON (t1.Id = t2.Id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET t1.Count = Coalesce(t1.Count,0) - Coalesce(t2.Count,0)
```

<kbd>[Demo for Oracle Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eac90c9ee195ca4e9ac8906b5b32e393)</kbd>

`Coalesce()` might be replaced with `Nvl()` for Oracle DB.